# Experience editor showing home page instead of specific page on refresh

Tags: experience-editor

While working in experience editor on certain page and when we refresh the page, the experience editor shows home page instead of that specific page. Now if we refresh the page again, the experience editor shows the desired specific page. Is this some issue with caching ?

Comment: Anything in the logs? Is the URL magically changing between refreshes? I would want to confirm that the sc_item query string is the same between refreshes. Does this happen in the web database context as well? Any custom redirects or URL rewrites in place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this issue fixed.

There were 2 errors in the logs related to this issue.

```
ERROR Item could not be found from query string. [ID is "{D3893543-5018-448A-825F-C41472C6AA88}".]

ERROR Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Exception: System.NullReferenceException
Message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Source: Score.Custom at Score.Custom.ExperienceEditor.Ribbon.Duplicate.CanDuplicateRequest.ProcessRequest() at Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak.Server.Requests.PipelineProcessorRequest`1.Process(RequestArgs requestArgs)
```

There were few customization done for the experience editor which checks the parent item of the page item which is opened in the experience editor. This customization was working fine until we enabled the enforce version presence feature. Once this feature was enabled, whenever there was no version for the parent item in th particular language then it throws null reference error and it cannot find the item.

This issue was fixed by disabling enforce version presence for the particular code.

```
using (new EnforceVersionPresenceDisabler())
{
  //Code 
}
```